# Do hatched pokemon have higher IV's?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have recently been looking at the hidden IV's of my pokemon and I noticed that the pokemon I get from hatching tends to be quite a bit higher than what I find in the wild. Do hatched pokemon tend to have higher IV's than ones in the wild?

Comment: "I noticed that the pokemon I get from hatching tends to be quite a bit higher than what I find in the wild." Seems like you answered your own question. Research and testing would have to be done but i feel like your assumption is probably right

Comment: Just because I noticed a slight trend doesn't mean it's true for other people and the purpose of this is to look at a larger sample size.

Comment: Also this is definitely not a duplicate because the post does not mentions IV's at all.

Comment: ^ beat me to it

Comment: Can anybody explain what is IV?

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate; it doesn't have to mention IVs for it to be.  It asks if eggs are better in *any* way.  I don't think IVs even exist in Go.

Comment: And none of the answers even mention the word IV. Also IV's definitely exist in Go, just look at the SilphRoad subreddit. If none of the questions in the "duplicate" question even come close to answering my question what should I do? Definitely not just post a new question that is more specific.

Comment: @DeMize "individual values".. the hidden stats that produce the CP rating. I believe Go has Attack, Defense and Stamina

Comment: While IV's do exist there is no reason to believe that hatched Pokemon are better than caught ones. There has been evidence found in what has been data mined, and from personal experience and other individual reports it appears there isn't an advantage one way or the other. I've hatched ones that have incredibly low stats (CP, HP, and IV) and caught some that are very high. Only change I can tell is trainer level and luck.

Comment: This question is unfortunate because it's technically a duplicate, but you're right that the other question is entirely full of incorrect answers, since none mention that bred and lured Pokemon tend to have higher IVs than those caught normally.